# Writing memoize function without ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript

I am working on a problem and I am not allowed to use ES6 syntax so I can't use the spread/rest operator. How can I write a function that will take any number of arguments without a spread/rest operator?

```js
function memoize(func) {
    var cache = {};
    return function (...args) {
      if (args in cache) {
        return cache[args];
      } else {
        cache[args] = func(...args);
        return func(...args);
      }
    };
};
```

Comment: Use the `arguments` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Use the `arguments` variable in combination with `Function.prototype.apply`. Eg: `func.apply(this, arguments)`

Comment: `.apply()` is like `.call()` but expects an array instead of argument list - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object. It is an older feature which makes a variable called `arguments` available in non arrow functions. The value of `arguments` is all the arguments a function receive. It is an array-like object, not an array. This eliminates the use of rest operator.

Also, it is better to create a key, when you are creating a generic function.
**Why?** Javascript object keys can only be string. If an object is used as a key it gets auto converted to a string : `[object Object]`. So basically all your object keys will override each other. Here is a demo:

```js
const obj1 = { a : 1};
const obj2 = { b : 2};

const x = {};
x[obj1] = 2;
console.log(x);

x[obj2] = 2;
console.log(x);
```

To generate hash key you could use any method. Below is not a bullet proof implementation but I have just joined all the arguments into a `.` separated array.

Now we have to call your function with these arguments, in the else condition. **How?** When you want to forward you arguments to another function, and they are in the form of an array, you can use something like [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). It is pre ES6 feature which lets you run a function in a different context, or lets you pass arguments as an **array**. Here we won't be changing the context, but the second use case is what we will be using.

```js
function memoize(func) {
    var cache = {};
    return function () {
    const key = Object.values(arguments).join('.');
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log(cache);
      if (key in cache) {
        return cache[key];
      } else {
        cache[key] = func.apply(null,arguments);
        return  cache[key];
      }
    };
};

const conc = (str,str2,str3) => `${str}_${str2}_${str3}`;


const memoizedSq = memoize(conc);

memoizedSq('hello','hi','hey');
memoizedSq('bye','see you','so long');
memoizedSq('hello','hi','hey');
```

I have used [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create the string.

Minor optimization I did by changing your code in the else condition is not calling function multiple times. I just saved it in the object and returned the same value.

Note: This could break for cases where if a function takes a string, and the string itself contains `.`.